# How do I send a confirmation email to an email address inside a repeating section in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to send a confirmation email to an email address inside a repeating section.

[image: Confirmation]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

We have been looking into this a bit and we have found that you can do this by using a Calculation and an extra Email field outside of the Repeating Section.

Start out with a normal Repeating Section and a normal Email Field inside of the Repeating Section.

=RepeatingSection.Where(ItemNumber=1).Select(Email).First()

This will only use the first Repeating Sections Email address, Item 1, and pull the email address out of the Repeating Section and place it into the Email address outside of the Repeating Section. You can then use this email address in the 'To' field in the Confirmation settings.

This is what the form will look like in the builder:
[image]

You will then be able to add the Email Calculation field to the Confirmation 'To' field:
[image]